# add html text with javascript

Tags: javascript

i am adding a input file tag and a link using a javascript function, works great. Now i want to add also a radio button and a text whit this radio... i can add the radio whit no problems, but the text... idk how.

here is the code...

```
addCampo = function () {  
    nDiv = document.createElement('div');
    nDiv.className = 'archivo';
    nDiv.id = 'file' + (++numero);


    nCampo = document.createElement('input');
    nCampo.name = 'archivos[]';
    nCampo.type = 'file';

    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.name = nDiv.id;
    a.href = '#';
    a.onclick = elimCamp;
    a.innerHTML = ' Eliminar';

    portada = document.createElement('input');
    portada.name = 'portada';
    portada.type = 'radio';
    portada.value = '1';

    nDiv.appendChild(nCampo);
    nDiv.appendChild(portada);

    // HERE I WANT A SIMPLE TEXT SAYING WHATS DOES THE RADIO =) 

    nDiv.appendChild(a);

    container = document.getElementById('adjuntos');
    container.appendChild(nDiv);
}
```

this is working just fine! the only thing i dont know is how to add text whitout tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
text = document.createTextNode('what the radio does');
nDiv.appendChild(text);
```

Although it's better to use a label, because then you don't have to sharp-shoot the radio button.  In that case you'd need:

```
portada.id = 'portada';
text = document.createElement('label');
text.innerText = 'what the radio does';
text.for = 'portada';
nDiv.appendChild(text);
```

Edit: as mentioned in the comments, innerText is not necessarily supported by all browsers, sorry!  Just use innerHTML instead, use textContent if you don't care about old versions of IE, or create a text node and add it to the label node.

Comment: `innerText` may be not recognized by all browsers, for example Firefox knows only `textContent`.